# Can we have both Go and Next buttons in android keypad

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

I like to design a form with both **Go** and **Next** buttons in keypad. I think we can have any one button (either 'go' or 'next' button) at a time in android keypad (please correct me if I am wrong). Is there any option to have both these buttons displayed to user.

Consider that I have a form with two EditTexts. The first EditText is mandatory and the second EditText is optional. Hence, once user completes their first EditText value, they can either

- click Next button - to point second EditText (or)
- click Go button - to directly submit the form values.

Please suggest me some sample codes if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you can't have both buttons together.

Comment: you can make a work around with the Softkeyboard button next that When you click on next pop up a dialog which ask your requirment on cancle request focus to next edittext field on ok submit the form values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the standard keyboard. The "Go" and "Next" buttons are "contextual" - they are supposed to represent actions depending on the current state.

If there are more text boxes to fill, the "Next" should be displayed, if not, then "Go" should move the user to the next screen or action.

You can make your own custom keyboard that overrides this behavior but I would advise against it as it would end up confusing the users since they are already used to this behavior. This falls under the design principle: **If it looks the same, it should act the same** (Under the [Simplify My Life](https://developer.android.com/design/get-started/principles.html#simplify-my-life) section)

Comment: Hi Anup.. Thanks for the reply. Even I don't like to have both GO and NEXT buttons in the same keyboard. However, my requirement forces me to do that badly. You have mentioned about 'custom keyboard'.. Can you please provide some more thoughts on this. Is there any open source api or code to customise android keypad, so that I can add some additional buttons and actions to it. Once again thanks for your detail explanation and time.

Comment: making a custom keyboard is not a trivial task. It's a whole project in itself.It'll take months, not days. Even if you make one of these, you'll have to get the user to install this keyboard app and make it the default keyboard on their system before you can see this in any app. All this for an extra button? I'd suggest you have a talk with your designers and tell them to come up with a better solution to whatever it is you are trying to achieve.